# Magento 2 - Get product list price and multiply by 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, php, category

I have the following Cart Price Rule:

[image]

How I can display the rule in product list page? I need to have something like:

```
1 + 1 = 78$
```

Basically I need to get the base price *2 - 10.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be quite difficult to accomplish `Cart Price Rules`. `Cart Price Rules` are applied to carts, and calculate on the products in that cart. There is no direct way of accessing them from a catalog product. https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html

For rules applied to products in the catalog, you will want to use `Catalog Price Rules`, but there is no way to add quantity as a conditional. https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html

To accomplish what you want for this product, you may consider using `Tier Pricing` to offer different prices for specified quantities. https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html

Using `Tier Pricing` you can then update your theme to display the pricing however you wish on the product list and product detail pages.